# Remove empty rows in table - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a system that when user enter a value into the input field, it will generate a table and the number of rows will be the value that the user entered.

User can change the input field whenever they like. For example, user enters 4 to the input field-> system generates 4 rows -> user changed to 6 -> system add 2 row to make it a total of 6 rows.

Input field:[image: input field]
Generate table rows:[image: table]

If user changes the input value after, there are 3 conditions:

**IF input value < table length, remove empty rows only.(Not Working, need help on this)**

[image]: for this case, no matter user changed the value to 3/2/1/0, only the 4th row will be removed because the first 3 rows are filled.

```
    if(document.getElementById("stationcodetemp").value<lengtht){
        
        for(var x=0; x<lengtht; x++){
            var empty = false;
            if(document.getElementsByName("stationcode")[x].value == ''){
            empty = true;
            
            }
            if(empty == true){

              document.getElementById("tblItem").deleteRow([x]); //this function is working, but it is not removing the correct row
            }

        }
```

**IF input value == table length, do nothing (working)**

```
       }else if(document.getElementById("stationcodetemp").value==lengtht){
           //When input value == table length, do nothing 
       }else{
```

**IF input value > table length, add row to the table (working)**

```
        while ( lengtht < value){
            addRowToEquipmentTableR();
             lengtht++;        //When input value > table length, + row
        }
       }

}
```

Comment: Why not just add the remove code in the if statement instead of having `empty=true`?

Comment: you misspelled `length`